# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, dll, wamp, wampserver

> 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_smtp.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I get the above error message. I checked the phpinfo and installed the latest version too. But still I get the same error.

1. I clicked on Apache->Version on wamp to reload and I get the above mentioned error.
2. Whenever I start wamp I get the above mentioned error.

Before it was working fine, I don't know what happened now. Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: is it for win 32 bit?

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no `php_smtp.dll` in PHP. See this for one option for sending mail from a windows PHP http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am using PHP Mailer and it needs php_smtp.dll to send mails..So I am getting this error even after reinstalling and trying out all the possible methods to fix this error which I found on stackoverflow and some other websites..

Comment: Where did you download the php_smtp.dll from?

Comment: Have you also enabled `php_openssl.dll`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I downloaded it from http://www.topdll.com/download/php_smtp.dll?q=888dc0c8f0e7636004f915b07cf6e448

And openssl is enabled.. As I was saying, before it was working fine and suddenly it stopped working and errors started appearing..

Comment: PHPMailer does not use `php_smtp.dll` it uses sockets to connect to the SMTP server. These is no php_smtp.dll code in the PHP code base, so I have to assume php_smtp.dll is dangerous code developed for some other reason, possibly bad reasons, especially as it is only available from dodgy sites like`topdll.com` This is not the solution to your problem

Answer (score -1):

Try going to your `php.ini` file in your PHP folder and find `php_smtp.dll` and comment it.